# Centroids matlab without kmeans

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I need a clustering algorithm that return the centroids as kmeans does. I have been trying with kmeans but I know that depending on the shape of the cluster sometimes its not good.

I know matlab includes hierachical clustering, but that return me the index of the cluster that each point belongs, but not the centroids.

Comment: You can first do the clustering with whatever algorithm works, and then compute the centroid of each cluster yourself. `mean` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**Just compute the centroid.**

Algorithms that do not model the data using centroids (like k-means) *will* not provide you with a centroid; because it would cost extra time to compute the centroid, and many people won't need it. Why put that cost on everybody?

Note that for clusters of other shapes (except k-means, GMM etc.), the centroid is *much* less meaningful. Since the cluster can be arbitrary shape **the centroid could be outside of the cluster**. In particular when using other metrics - the center is a least-squares estimate; it optimizes variance aka: squared Euclidean distances. If you have a different distance function, the centroid may be a suboptimal choice as representative.